# faces components not being displayed

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am trying to make a very simple application. With a starting menu as a welcome page, however I am having problems with faces components not being displayed.

The relevant snippet of my web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>menu.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<filter>
    <filter-name>WelcomeFileFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>giu.WelcomeFileFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>WelcomeFileFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/menu.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My menu.xhtml file

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:form id="menuForm">
    <h1><h:outputText id="menuTitle" value="Menu Principal"/></h1><br/><br/>
    <h3><h:outputText id="patientsTitle" value="Pacientes"/></h3><br/>
    <h:panelGrid id="patientsGrid" columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Consultar, Crear, Editar o Eliminar Paciente"/>
        <p:commandButton id="goToPatientsButton" value="Ir"/>
    </h:panelGrid><br/><br/>
    <h3><h:outputText id="doctorsTitle" value="Medicos"/></h3><br/>
    <h:panelGrid id="doctorsGrid" columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Consultar, Crear, Editar o Eliminar Medicos"/>
        <p:commandButton id="goToDoctorsButton" value="Ir"/>
    </h:panelGrid><br/><br/>
    <h3><h:outputText id="medicalHistoryTitle" value="Historias Medicas"/></h3><br/>
    <h:panelGrid id="medicalHistoryGrid" columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Consultar, Crear, Editar o Eliminar Historias Medicas"/>
        <p:commandButton id="goToMedicalHistoriesButton" value="Ir"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:dataTable emptyMessage="Vacio" paginator="true"/>
</h:form>
```

I dont know what am I doing wrong, plain html components such as texts and buttons display correctly, however primefaces components such as datatables and messages are not being displayed.

If it serves for anything, my question is closely related to: [How to set 'JSF2 welcome-file' with faces servlet mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616493/how-to-set-jsf2-welcome-file-with-faces-servlet-mapping)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<welcome-file>` cannot be a "virtual" URL. Define it to be `menu.xhtml` and create a `Filter` which is mapped on `/menu.xhtml` and redirects to the proper URL.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns={"/menu.xhtml"})
public class WelcomeFileFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("faces/menu.xhtml");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Or even better, you can also consider to just get rid of the `/faces/*` prefix mapping altogether in favour of an extension mapping. I recommend to use `*.xhtml` so that you never need to worry about the URLs and also not about the risk that the JSF source code get exposed when the enduser wishfully edits the URL to remove the JSF mapping.

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>menu.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Hi Balus, dont know exaclty where the _webcontent root_ is sorry for the probably silly question

Comment: It's the folder where all your public web files are. It's the folder where the `/WEB-INF` folder is sitting in. By the way, I now realize that this is not necessary as you're using the same file extension, I updated the answer accordingly. By the way, why wouldn't you just go for the extension mapping? It's much clearer and easier.

Comment: Oh, well I have a non empty _menu.xhtml_ right there, with your answer the displaying of the page is being done but without any faces components..

Comment: You still need to create the filter which is mapped on an URL pattern of `/menu.xhtml` and redirects to `faces/menu.xhtml` so that the URL in browser address bar ends up to be http://localhost:8080/contextname/faces/menu.xhtml. This way the `FacesServlet` will be invoked and do all the JSF works.

Comment: I added an example to the answer. The interface requires two more methods, but their bodies can be left empty. Just have your IDE auto-generate them.

Comment: Got that, check my updated web.xml I tried to reference the filter there, but no luck, thanks!

Comment: Only added the filter part to the .xml but now it is updated correctly yet having the same faces problem. Going home now, I really appreciate your time and help /salute

Comment: I see that you changed the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` as well. This way you don't need the filter at all. My answer is basically suggesting two different solutions. Keep the new URL pattern and remove the filter. The problem is caused by something else. Rightclick the page in webbrowser and choose *View Source*. Are all JSF tags turned into HTML? If so, then the `FacesServlet` is doing its job perfectly. If you *actually* mean that the PrimeFaces components doesn't have CSS applied, then it means that you don't have a `<h:head>` in the template.