# How to set default home while developing jsf applications

Tags: jsf

I am developing a jsf application, and my application is already on the production environment. But there is something i want to know: if my domain name is: "mydomain.com" and in my application the home page is: "home.jsf", i would like my application to display the home page directly  when i visit: www.mydomain.com

But what is happening now is to get my home page to display, i must write: www.mydomain.com/home.jsf . This seems to me very tedious.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just mention the welcome file in your web.xml as follows:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as JSF is concern, adding a simple welcome file wont produce good result. In addition to home.xhtml file, create an empty home.jsf file..  the server will not run the empty file (home.jsf) , wherelse it will proceed with home.xhtml. Then declare the welcome file in web.xml. for more have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4618142/839393