# ServletException Login Fail - WildFly and JDBC Realm

Tags: jsf, authentication, wildfly, jdbcrealm

I have a Java EE 6 project with JSF and WildFly as an application server.

I want to realize the JDBC Realm for authentication, but I got a Login Failed exception (`javax.servlet.ServletException`)

This is my Login.xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/main.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="nologin" value="true" />
    <ui:define name="insert-title">
        <h:outputText value="Kundenverwaltung - Login"/>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="insert-content">
        <h:form> 
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Username" />
                <p:inputText type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username"
                    value="#{securityStatus.userName}" />
                <p:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password" />
                <p:inputText type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password"
                    value="#{securityStatus.password}" />
                <p:commandButton name="login" id="login" value="Login"
                    action="#{securityActions.login}" ajax="false" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

</html>
```

This is my SecurityAction Bean: This is the class where i get the Exception LoginFail in the catch Block of ServletException

```
public String login() {
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest = getHttpRequest();

    try {
        servletRequest.login( securityStatus.getUserName(), securityStatus.getPassword() );
        securityStatus.setLoggedIn( true );
        logger.debug( "user has logged in." );
        return PATH_VIEWS_PROJECT + VIEW_PROJECT_OVERVIEW;
    } catch ( ServletException e ) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        securityStatus.setLoggedIn( false );
        logger.debug( "user was not logged in." );
        return PATH_VIEWS_SECURITY + VIEW_LOGIN;
    }
}
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>web</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<!-- general faces mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- special faces mapping, only needed for welcome file. 
     see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616493/how-to-set-jsf2-welcome-file-with-faces-servlet-mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>/views/security/login.faces</welcome-file> 
     <!-- <welcome-file>/views/project/project-input.xhtml</welcome-file> -->
    <!--  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> -->
</welcome-file-list>

    <security-constraint>
    <!-- handles "No authenticator available for programmatic login" on JBoss 
        AS -->
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>all-pages</web-resource-name>
        <description>Sicherheitsumgebung für alle Seiten</description>
        <url-pattern>/faces/views/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <description>normal users, have read-only access to data</description>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description>privileged admins, have full access to data</description>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>jaas-realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/views/security/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/faces/views/security/not-logged-in.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/faces/views/security/not-logged-in.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

This is my jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss>
    <security-domain>jaas-realm</security-domain>
</jboss>
```

And this is my security Domain configuration in the standalone-full.xml of Jboss

```
<security-domain name="jaas-realm">
    <authentication>
     <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/mydb"/>
        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from person where emailaddress=?"/>
        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select rolename, 'Roles' from userrole where emailaddress=?"/>
        <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
        <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
     </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

The SecurityAction can not do this method successfully:

```
servletRequest.login( securityStatus.getUserName(), securityStatus.getPassword() );
```

And I got the following stack-trace:

```
[io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.login(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:440)
 de.web.actions.security.SecurityActions.login(SecurityActions.java:42)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:292)
 com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
 org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
 org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
 org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
 org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
 com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
 javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
 com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
 javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
 javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
 javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
 de.web.web.filters.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:21)
 io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
 org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
 io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
 io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
 io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
 io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
 io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
 io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
 io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
 org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
 io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
 io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
 io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
 io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
 io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)]
```

Comment: Your stacktrace doesn't say much. Do you have more of it?

Comment: no sorry, thats also the Problem why it is hard to locate the error for me

Comment: This is not a full stacktrace. Please check again